# How can I first sort by color & then in alphabetical order in ssrs?

Tags: sorting, ssrs-2016

I'm still new to ssrs. In my query the color is determined by location. In my query I did 
ORDER BY [Location], Underwriter. Now this works perfectly fine in my query, but when I run it in SSRS it doesn't sort like in the query. I get this[image]

what I would like to do is first group the colors together and & set the underwriters in alphabetical order i.e. Balluka, Bill(light blue)
           Matanane, Brian(green)
           Walsh, Daniel(green)
           Davidson, Christine (pink)
           Hamilton, Marianne (pink)
           Karger, Tierney (pink)
           Marroquin, Melanie (pink)
           Sylvester, Todd (pink)
           Hopp, Robert (white)
           Lohr, Jeff (white)
           Raskovic, Hanna (white)

Now what I tried doing in ssrs was in the design I right clicked underwriter> interactive sorting: tried sorting by underwriter & location but nothing happens when I run it. Please help 
 [image: s]

Answer (score 0):

The order by clause in your SQL query should have worked.

Since it isn't working that means that something else is interfering with the sort order.

The next place to look is in your **Tablix Properties** under sorting.

Then look at any **Group Properties.** Make sure you check *each* row.

If you still can't find it, right click on the report in Visual studio and **view code**. You can then Ctr-F and search for "Sort" and find any sort expressions in the .rdl.

If you find an object you want to look at, you can then use search properties to select the object by name.